# Spark writing output back to the input directory

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I recently encountered a scenario where I need to read input from HDFS from a directory

```
 /user/project/jsonFile
```

and write the result back to the same directory:

```
 /user/project/jsonFile
```

After reading jsonFile multiple joins are performed and the result is written to /user/project/jsonFile using:

```
result.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("/user/project/jsonFile");
```

Below is the error I see:

```
[task-result-getter-0]o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 2508, hddev1db015dxc1.dev.oclc.org, executor 3): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/project/jsonFile
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:77)
    
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:177)
```

Why is it throwing `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist?` `result` is the dataset containing the output for the joins that is written back to HDFS, once `result` dataset is available shouldnt spark be able to write data back to HDFS in the same input dir?

Or

this makes me think that some executors completed its join on the input and they are ready to write the result back to HDFS whereas some executors are still in the process of reading the data from same HDFS dir which is being overwritten now causing a FileNotFound. Is that true?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is it that jsonFile is a directory?  Try writing to a file under  there?  Double check the api to write a partitioned DF in to a directory...

Comment: yes, jsonFile is a directory. I am trying to write files under that.

Comment: @NeethuLalitha could this be solved with dynamic overwrite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using overwrite when reading and writing from the same dir. One way to to is use Append instead of Overwrite

```
result.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).json("/user/project/jsonFile");
```

Another workaround is to store write your data in  another folder and then and read from it as the source to your initial location.

```
read from source
make your data transformations
write transformed data into tempLocation
read from tempLocation
write into source
```